# Limits of the Communities Basic HTML Header

Tags: community

I have a couple of questions around the Communities Basic branding options.

1. In a HTML header file, is it possible to include the user name drop down (My Profile, My Settings, and Logout)?
2. I am trying to include a jPanelMenu (http://jpanelmenu.com/). In order to include this you instantiate the menu an the code create a couple of divs, one is a wrapper div around the page content and it also appends an attribute to the <body> tag. I have this working in a HTML page, but when I add this to the Header in the Branding of the communities it doesn't work. Is this even possible?

My thought is these 2 things are not possible with basic branding. Do I need to use custom VF pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best example of this is in the Salesforce Success Community. The way it is accomplished there, is that they have a very basic Visualforce page called [UserInfo that spits out JSON](https://success.salesforce.com/userinfo):

Here is controller for a different example of the same concept from the Foundation's community, the Power of Us Hub:

```
public class HubUserInfoController {

public string userInfoJson { get; private set; }

//public to allow this subclass to be accessible to a test class
public class HubUser {
    public string fullName;
    public string email;
    public string userId;
    public boolean isLoggedIn;
    public string profilePicUrl;
    public string profileOverviewUrl;
    public string profileFeedUrl;
    public string profileMyOrgUrl;
    public string profileBadgesUrl;
    public string recommendationsUrl;
}

public HubUserInfoController() {
    HubUser hu = getUserInfo();
    userInfoJson = JSON.serialize(hu);
}

private HubUser getUserInfo() {
    User runningUser = [
        SELECT      Name, Id, SmallPhotoUrl, Email, Profile.UserType
        FROM        User
        WHERE       Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()
    ];

    HubUser newHU = new HubUser();
    if (runningUser.Profile.UserType == 'Guest') {
        newHU.isLoggedIn = false;
    } else {
        newHU.fullName = runningUser.Name;
        newHU.email = runningUser.Email;
        newHU.userId = runningUser.Id;
        newHU.isLoggedIn = true;
        newHU.profilePicUrl = runningUser.smallPhotoUrl;
        newHU.profileOverviewUrl = '/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=' + runningUser.Id + '&tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformOverview';
        newHU.profileFeedUrl = '/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=' + runningUser.Id + '&tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformFeed';
        newHU.profileMyOrgUrl = '/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=' + runningUser.Id + '&tab=My_Org';
        newHU.profileBadgesUrl = '/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=' + runningUser.Id + '&tab=sfdc.Recognition';
        newHU.recommendationsUrl = '/_ui/core/chatter/recommend/RecommendationsPage?recType=GROUPS';
    }

    return newHU;
}
}
```

And the VF page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" contentType="application/x-JavaScript; charset=utf-8" controller="HubUserInfoController">{!userInfoJson}</apex:page>
```

And then in your header, you'd have some JS relying on jQuery, that looks like this to build the menu:

```
var userInfo = {};

j$(document).ready(function(){
    j$.getJSON( "/apex/userInfo" )
        .done(function( json ) {
        userInfo = json;
        for (var key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            populateUserNavItem(key);
        }
    }

    //populate the user info
    if (json.isLoggedIn) {
            j$(".user-nav-thumbnail").attr("src", json.profilePicUrl);
            j$("#fullName").text(json.fullName);
            j$(".dropdown-header-email").text(json.email);
            j$(".user-nav").show();
            j$(".search-box").css('display', 'inline-block');

});

function populateUserNavItem(selector) {
    j$("." + selector).attr("href", userInfo[selector]);
}
```

Lastly, some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="user-nav dropdown dropdown-toggle" style="display:none;">
        <img class="user-nav-thumbnail" src="/profilephoto/005/T" style="height:24px; width:24px;"/>
        <span class="caret" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right user-nav-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="user-nav-dropdown">
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-name"><a class="profileOverviewUrl" href="#"><span id="fullName"></span><span class="dropdown-header-email"></span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a class="profileOverviewUrl" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user pull-right"></span>My Profile</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a class="profileFeedUrl" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment pull-right"></span>My Posts/Questions</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a class="profileMyOrgUrl" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase pull-right"></span>My Org</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a class="profileBadgesUrl" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate pull-right"></span>My Badges</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a class="recommendationsUrl" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up pull-right"></span>Recommended for Me</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/publogout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out pull-right"></span>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="login-action" style="display:none;">
   <a type="button" href="#" id="hub-login-button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Login <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" style="vertical-align:text-top;"></span></a>
</div>
```